# Html/JQuery: Button loses focus after Page refresh

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, focus

I have a html page which refreshes every two seconds. Unfortunately the focus on the button clicked before gets lost. Is there a method with JQuery (or something else) to remember the focus on the button?

Comment: How are you "refreshing" the page?  location.href?  ajax?  Can you add code to you page?  Can you change the url?   If you use ajax, no problem.  Otherwise, pass a parameter on the url and check for it on load (eg "url?focused=mybutton1")

Comment: You can focus your button manually each time the browser refreshes.
`window.onload = function() {
   button.focus();
}`